# network services reachability troubleshooting

Tags: networking, network-interface, troubleshooting, netstat

I have voyage linux on a system. It is running an apache server and an sshd. For some reason, i cannot connect to those services from another machine. There are no error logs that i have been able to find. A client can ping the linux system but it cannot access `ssh` or `www`. If I try to connect locally to sshd by issuing `ssh root@127.0.0.1`, I am successful. Further, `netstat -l` produces lines that show things such as:
`tcp *:ssh listen`

The system is offline, that means one can only connect to it directly with an ethernet cable (no switch, no internet access). It is running as embedded pc in a machine.

What other steps can i try to figure out why it is not possible to connect to those services and to make it work again?

Comment: If you can, install `tracepath` it's  `traceroute` for TCP.

Comment: If ping works it looks it's not a routing problem, but more likely a firewall configuration preventing access (except to ping).